# How to convert 2D list python into one list with concate them

Tags: python, list, machine-learning

I have question here, and i have done to do what i can do,
The problem is i have Multi List  python

```
[[1,3,4,2],[2,2,3,1],[2,1,2,3]
```

i want make this list to become like this

```
[[1,2,2],[3,2,1],[4,3,2],[2,1,3]]
```

Thanks in advance,

its my code to try but separate into 2 list, i want make it into one like my question

```
list1 = [1,4,2,5]
list2 = [2,1,5,3]
list3 = [list(a) for a in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: please don't edit "Closed" (or similar) into the title of your question when it's received an answer you're happy with, that's not how things work on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fianeka, Actually, it's [even simpler than that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53790312/4046632) :-) Of course if you a fine with list of tuples.

```
some_list = [[1,3,4,2],[2,2,3,1],[2,1,2,3]]
print(list(zip(*some_list)))
```

output:

```
[(1, 2, 2), (3, 2, 1), (4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list(map(list, zip(*list1)))
```

Simple like that.